Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
getting below error while trying to connect debezium with kafka

.\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat config/connect-standalone.properties config/postgres.properties

INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:57)
ERROR Failed to create connector for config/postgres.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:85)
ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:96)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector, available connectors....
folder structure and kafka & debezium versions
postgres.properties
connect-standalone
debezium folder
my java version:
C:\kafka\debezium-connector-postgres>java --version
openjdk 17.0.11 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 17.0.11+9-adhoc..jdk17u)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 17.0.11+9-adhoc..jdk17u, mixed mode, sharing)
Tried by adding multiple paths like debezium path, kafka lib paths etc..
Still not able to execute the .\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat config/connect-standalone.properties config/postgres.properties
